# how to cast to string in python 2.7 in spark udf and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark

i have this problem, i write spark code in python 2.7 it is a udf but when i pass the column that i want to handle, this error appears

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd0'
```

and this is my spark udf :

```
def validate_rule(string):
  search_list=[" ",'!','%','$',"<",">","^",'¡',"+","N/A",u'¿','~','#','Ñ',"Ã","Åƒ","Ã‹","Ã³",'Ë','*','?',"ILEGIBLE", "VICIBLE","VISIBLE","INCOMPLETO"]
  str_temp = string
  if str_temp.upper() == "BORRADO":
    return 1
  elif len(str_temp) < 6:
    return 1
  elif any(ext in str_temp.upper()for ext in search_list):
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

df_ =df.withColumn("data",validate_rule_udf(col("data_to_procces"))
```

the error appears in:

```
df_.show() or df_.toPandas()
```

and also when i use pandas apply funtion with this lamda:

```
pdDF["data_to_procces"].apply(lambda x:validate_rule(x) )
```

the error appears again.

I have already used and it has not worked :

```
string.econde("utf-8") and unicode(string, 'utf-8')
```

complete error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

```
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
```

Comment: If you could provide the sample data of `df` it would help us to debug

Comment: i´m  using jupyter and load from spark : df_load =spark.sql("SELECT * FROM 
 tabla").cache()#.toPandas(), this column  data_to_procces is string type  and they are alphanumeric serial numbers like : ass76575jhzxzx78

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack trace, not just the EncodeError.

Answer (score 0):

1. You wouldn’t be experiencing this problem if you were using Python 3.
2. The cause of this issue is that your `search_list` inside `validate_rule` mixes Python 2 strings (which are really just bytes) with Python 2 Unicode strings (sequences of Unicode code points).

When the 3rd condition, `any(ext in str_temp.upper()for ext in search_list)`, is evaluated, `str_temp` is a Unicode object (because Spark adheres to the Unicode sandwich rule, whereby it immediately decodes raw bytes into Unicode at the input (so, when loading data) and encodes the Unicode strings back to bytes at the output.

Now, Python 2 will try to convert each `ext` to a Unicode object to be able to evaluate the statement `ext in str_temp.upper()`. This works fine for the first few characters of `search_list`, because they’re all in the ASCII range, but fails as soon as it encounters the bytestring `'¡'`. With that, it tries to call 
`'¡'.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())` and that will fail if your locale’s preferred encoding is ASCII.

You might think, “sure, I’ll explicitly decode each of those bytestrings using `utf-8`”, like this:

```py
any(ext.decode("utf-8") in str_temp.upper()for ext in search_list)
```

but that won’t work either, because a little bit later in the `search_list` is a Unicode object: `u'¿'`. Calling `decode` on Unicode objects makes no sense. What will happen here is that Python 2 will implicitly convert (so, encode) your Unicode object back to bytes, because it recognizes you want to call `decode` on an object and that’s only intended for bytestrings. However `u'¿'.encode("ascii")` won’t work because the ASCII codec indeed does not have a reference for the inverted question mark codepoint.

## Solutions

- Work in Python 3. You really have no good reason to start developing in Python 2 anymore, as Python 2 will no longer be maintained from Jan 1st, 2020 on. Your code works perfectly under Python 3. Although you should no longer need to use `u` in front of Unicode strings.
- Have all of the symbols in `search_list` properly encoded to Unicode objects.
  This would be the bare minimum you would need to have:

```py
def validate_rule(str):
    search_list = [" ", '!', '%', '$', "<", ">", "^", u'¡', 
                   "+", "N/A", u'¿', '~', '#', u'Ñ', u"Ã",
                   u"Åƒ", u"Ã‹", u"Ã³", u'Ë',
                   '*', '?', "ILEGIBLE", "VICIBLE", "VISIBLE", "INCOMPLETO"]
    if str.upper() == "BORRADO":
        return 1
    elif len(str) < 6:
        return 1
    elif any(ext in str.upper() for ext in search_list):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Here, I got away with not having to prepend every bytestring with `u` to create Unicode strings, because the remaining bytestrings are in the ASCII table, which is a subset of UTF-8. Still, it’s recommended to be explicit and use Unicode strings everywhere in your `search_list`.